# dimension of kernel and image of isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

T:V ->V is isomorphism, dim V = n. The kernel of isomorphism has only vector 0 in it, so by rank nullity theorem does it mean that dim of kernel is 1 and dim of image is n-1?

the question seems a little silly but I wasn't sure. thanks

Comment: Dimension of kernel is $0$ and dimension of range is $n$.

Comment: See that **Empty set generates $\{0\}$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned right, that the kernel consists of only one point. But a space consisting of one point has dimension 0! This should answer your question. Maybe think about what a 1-dimensional space looks like.